# How to create m2m dependencies?

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

How to do when creating a `Student` instance in the database, a relationship will be created between the `Student` instance and a number of instances of the `Course` model:
-Every instantiated Student model must have a default relationship to some `Course` instances
-User cannot manually visit other parts of the site to add a new relationship between `Student` and `Course`.

```
models.py:
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=249)


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=249)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='Connect')

    
class Connect(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class CreateStudent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/admin/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index'
    template_name = 'app/create_student.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need code to create the relationships before you save the Student. If you stick with CreateView, you might replace the form_valid method to modify the student object and create other associated objects before the student object is saved.

[Classy CBV CreateView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/)

So on your view, something like

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    self.object = form.save( commit=False )

    # code to create related objects goes here

    # commit the student to the database
    self.object.save() 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```